# In place RDS upgrade

Tags: windows-server-2016, remote-desktop-services, windows-server-2019

I'm looking for a solution to upgrade RDS farm with 2 brokers servers from windows 2016 to 2019.

I read the online documentation by Microsoft for upgrading RDS and I get an error when I do the upgrade for one of the two broker servers.
Once one of them is in the process of upgrading, it is no longer compatible with the other. Shutting down both servers for an upgrade is a bit tricky, we have hundreds of users accessing the network via those servers and we don't want to isolate them.

Anyone who perform RDS upgrade with broker servers farm who can share advice?

TYIA!

Comment: Hm, i mind remembering, that a downtime should be planned